# How to invoke a string from a class using method.invoke(-,-)

Tags: java, parsing

Here i am trying to get `uContainer` object from another project. uContainer having all the setters and getters with return values set from `properties file`. Like a user properties for perticular user. I am using to get perticular method values from uContainer instance. But in the 4th line my application getting crashed.

uContainer is an instance of UserContainer class.

`getSingleResultListing` also a boolean variable in `UserContainer` class having with getters and setters methods.

The code is given below.

```
Method getUContainer = form.getClass().getMethod("getUserContainer", new Class[0]);
Object uContainerObj = (Object)getUContainer.invoke(form, new Object[0]);
Method getFlagValueMethod = uContainerObj.getClass().getMethod("getSingleResultListing", new Class[0]);
String flagValue = (String)getFlagValueMethod.invoke(uContainerObj, new Object[0]);
log.info(">>>flagValue: "+flagValue);
boolean singleListingFlag = Boolean.getBoolean(flagValue);
log.info(">>>singleListingFlag: "+singleListingFlag);
```

here in the fourth line while invoking the uContainer object i am getting error ..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the returned object to a `String`, but you are not getting a `String` from that method. You cannot convert objects to String via a cast operator. If you want the string representation, write

```
String flagValue = getFlagValueMethod.invoke(uContainerObj, new Object[0]).toString();
```

Comment: Very Very Thanks..your code is working great. i did't get the idea to use the toString() method. It helped me alot.